# Composer PSR-4 Autoloader Class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

here is my file structure

```
├── index.php
├── composer.json
├── src
    ├── Core
        └── Database.php
├── vendor
```

In my composer.json file I have

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Site\\": "src/"}
    }
```

In my Database.php

```
namespace Core;

class Database {}
```

And in my index.php

```
 $db = new Site\Core\Database();
```

But I get an error: Class 'Site\Core\Database' not found .

I have ran an `composer update` and `composer dump-auto -o` but still without success. I have looked at many of the other similar questions there are here but they have not helped.

Thank you

Comment: Your `Database` class is just in the `Core` namespace. Either change your composer entry to load `Core` from `src/` or add `Site\ ` to your Database namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `psr-4` like this in `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Site\\": "src/"}
}
```

It mean `Autoloader` will look for file `src/Core/Database.php` for  class `Site\Core\Database`.

But make sure in `Database.php` you define `namespace`

```
namespace Site\Core;

class Database
{
}
```

And the problem,  you just define `namespace Core;`

Comment: I updated my namespace but I still get the same error.

Comment: @ccKep, Fixed it. It wa due to a typo.

Comment: @FrenchMajesty How did you solve it? I have the same problem and I tried different namespaces but I always get the error `Class 'Foo\Bar\Core\User' not found`

Comment: @AlexPavlov Make sure that the namespace that you're using for your autoload (for example `Site`) is also namespaced in your class like in the code example.